# Push notifications not receiving/working for AppStore and TestFlight build

Tags: ios, push-notification, remote-notifications

As one of our iOS applications is UNABLE to receive push/remote notifications for production/live build which installed from App Store/TestFlight but able to receive push/remote notifications in development environment and even in production environment also app is able to receive push/remote notifications from third party services like Gimbal (which is in sync with Urban Airship) but not receiving in app notifications which triggered from our servers using Java code base.

We have cross checked

1. Push notifications permissions in iOS devices
2. Device token registration/update in our databases.
3. All ports which are needed for APNS are open in our servers firewall restrictions.
4. All the .p12 certificates which we are using for development and production are not expired and even we are able to send/trigger these push/remote notifications manually from third party portals(like pushtry.com website, NWPusher) by using the same .p12 certificates even in production environment to live build installed from App Store/TestFlight.

Need help/suggestions in this issue???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the host and port used in your server for production push notification.

I hope you are removing the sandbox from the host for production push notifications.